# Inductive types associated to instances of a structure in Lean

Tags: lean, inductive-type, examples

I am using the Lean computer proof assistant. I am using the combinatorial structure of a graph with an abelian operation on its edges as a learning example.

In it I have a structure Graph. **I want to have several inductive types associated to each particular structure g : Graph**; so that g.edges, g.vertices would or something like that. Then I want - basically, and in pseudocode - the following associated functions:

g.head : g.edges -> g.vertices

g.tail : g.edges -> g.vertices

g.multiplication : {(x, y) : g.vertices x g.vertices // g.tail(y) == g.head(x)} -> g.vertices

That's just an example so that people get the point. What I'm saying basically is that I want something which can play the role that a class within a class has in python. Structure is nice for very simple algebraic structures, but I want to be able to nest structures, put types of any kind internal to a structure (much like a class can go in a class in python).

Comment: Your `multiplication` doesn't type check. I assume you want `x` and `y` to be edges? Also, why do you want "inductive types"? How have you defined `Graph`? We will need more details. Are `g.edges` and `g.vertices` already part of your API?

Comment: "part of your API" - it was just pseudocode. I need something analogous to classes within classes in python. It should be a pretty simple task ... can you have structures within structures?

Comment: “Can you have a structure in a structure?”.  Absolutely, you can put any types you want in a structure.  (Well, structures aren’t recursive, and there are probably universe restrictions, but otherwise no limitations.)

Comment: But if you still feel this is not helpful, then I think you need to make a correct MWE api (maybe given in Python code) so we understand what you want.

Comment: I guess one pertinent question before we go much further is: are you going to use Lean 3's graphs as defined in its maths library or are you intending to roll your own?

Comment: @KevinBuzzard I was just using it as an example so I could see an example of a structure within a structure, implemented. So I'm not interested in graphs so much as the programming features necessary to make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Structure in structure" can mean many things.  Here are some interpretations:

Let's say you have the following directed graph implementation:

```
universe u
structure Graph (V : Type u) where
  is_edge : V -> V -> Prop

def my_example_graph : Graph Nat := { is_edge := fun x y => x < y }
```

(My examples are in Lean 4 and they are just quick examples.  The ideas are the same for Lean 3, but with different syntax.  See [this question for ways to define directed graphs in Lean](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1698/making-a-finite-graph-type-in-lean-introduction-rule))

It might be that after you define `Graph`, you want to be able to have extra methods for the `Graph` object.  In Lean this is easy to do for any type.  You don't have to modify `Graph` or wrap it in another type.  You just add those functions inside the `Graph` namespace.  This is the preferred way to add functions to any type including structures.

```
-- method 1: Just put namespace in definition name
def Graph.vertices {V : Type u} (g : Graph V) : Type u := V

-- method 2: enter namespace block
namespace Graph
   def is_source {V : Type u} (g : Graph V) (v : V) : Prop := ∃ w, g.is_edge v w
   def is_target {V : Type u} (g : Graph V) (v : V) : Prop := ∃ w, g.is_edge w v
end Graph

-- you can use project notation like follows
#check my_example_graph.vertices    -- Graph.vertices my_example_graph : Type
#check my_example_graph.is_source 0 -- Graph.is_source my_example_graph 0 : Prop
#check my_example_graph.is_target 0 -- Graph.is_target my_example_graph 0 : Prop
```

You can also wrap `Graph` in another structure or inductive:

```
structure GraphPair (V : Type u) where
  g1 : Graph V
  g2 : Graph V

inductive HigherOrderGraph
| LeafGraph : Graph Unit -> HigherOrderGraph
| GraphOfGraphs : Graph HigherOrderGraph -> HigherOrderGraph
```

A common use case is where you want to extend your structure with more fields.  Instead of wrapping it inside a structure, use `extends` as follows:

```
structure LabeledGraph (V : Type u) extends Graph V where
  L : Type u
  labels : (v w : V) -> is_edge v w -> L

def my_example_labeled_graph : LabeledGraph Nat :=
{ my_example_graph with
  L := Bool, 
  labels := fun x y _ => y > 0
}
```

See the [structure section of TPIL](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/structures_and_records.html) for more info.